# How do i apply lower_bound to a range of unsorted vector elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a vector of integer  `scores = 10, 23, 29, 77, 8, 43, 56, 3`
along with a number `predict = 42` 
and a `start index = 2`

I'm searching for two numbers, (more than and less than) close to `predict = 42` within range of `start index = 2` and `end index = 7`

> scores = {10, 23, **29, 77, 8, 43, 56, 3}** *(only search within range i=2 to i=7)*
>
> So, `29` is a little less than predict=42
>
> And, `43` is a little more then predict 42

How do I get these numbers?

Sample Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> scores = {10, 23, 29, 77, 8, 43, 56, 3}; //Unsorted
    int predict = 42;
    int startFromIndex = 2;
    
    int littleLessThanPredict; // = 29
    int littleMoreThanPredict; // = 43
    
    //lower_bound
    //upper_bound
    
    return 0;
}
```

Given this scenario,

1. How do i use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) functions on unsorted range?
2. How do i sort a part of a vector temporarily and apply my custom function?
3. is there a way to combine [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) functions to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Perhaps the assignment is for you to come up with an algorithm yourself? What are the requirements and limitations of the assignment? Where did you get the assignment from? Have you talked to your professor/teacher/teachers-assistant about this (if it's a school assignment)?

Comment: not a school assignment, its a console/text game, and, i am trying to implement this feature in one of the steps. I am unable to figure out the syntax for lambda functions, or out-of-place sort algorithm

Comment: I don't understand why you need `lower/upper_bound`. Can't you just for loop starting from `start index` and ending in `end index`, if you find a number lower than `predict` you save it in `littleLessThanPredict` and if it's bigger you save it in `littleMoreThanPredict`. Then keep going and if you find a number bigger than `littleLessThanPredict` but smaller than `predict` you update `littleLessThanPredict`, if you find a number smaller than `littleMoreThanPredict` but bigger than `predict` you update `littleMoreThanPredict`.

Comment: If scores were sorted, `lower_bound(scores.begin(), scores.end(), 42)` would return an iterator pointing to 43, not 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i use std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound functions on unsorted range?

No, they expect the range to be partitioned with respect to the value (all entries less than value must come before all the entries greater). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

> How do i sort a part of a vector temporarily and apply my custom function?

If you are dealing with numbers, maybe the easiest way would be to create a copy of the vector and sort that one. This is O(NlogN) complexity.

You might also get good performance by implementing lower_bound yourself (this will be O(N)).

Rule of thumb: If your array is usually short (<100 elements) just go with the copy and sort. The performance difference is not worth the effort.

> is there a way to combine std::min_element and std::lower_bound functions to obtain the desired result?

Not really.

Comment: if its a very large array? I'm looking for performance here

Comment: @PersistentCache in that case you need to implement the lower_bound yourself. It's a for loop where you look for the minimum element that is greater than the target value.

Comment: @PersistentCache "very large" is relative. Do you talk about thousands of elements? Tens of thousand? Hundreds of thousands? For thousands of elements, modern computers are plenty fast enough to handle even rather ineffective algorithms. Not to mention that for a console game the majority of the time will be the program sitting idle and waiting for input from the user.

Comment: @PersistentCache it's also good practice to profile your code. It can be that there are other hotspots that would make a bigger difference in the long run, compared to getting the best performance out of this.

Comment: ideally, vector size of 15,000 elements should do.

Comment: @PersistentCache Is 15000 the full array, or the slice you are searching through?

Comment: 15000 is full array. the slice sizes can be 1 to 14999.

Comment: thanks everyone for the feedback, no responses needed, i got to thinking and my problem is even bigger, might need dynamic programming and some sort of limiting factor.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to sort your array? That will give a **O(N.ln(N))** algorithm complexity.

You can do your algorithm in **O(N)** combining upper and lower bounds research in the unsorted array:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

pair<int, int> nearestNumbers(const vector<int> &scores, int predict, int start) {
    int nearestLower = INT_MIN;
    int nearestUpper = INT_MAX;

    for (size_t i = start; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        int value = scores[i];
        if (value <= predict && value > nearestLower)
            nearestLower = value;
        else if (value >= predict && value < nearestUpper)
            nearestUpper = value;
    }

    return pair<int, int>(nearestLower, nearestUpper);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> scores = {10, 23, 29, 77, 8, 43, 56, 3};
    int predict = 42;
    int start = 2;

    pair<int, int> results = nearestNumbers(scores, predict, start);
    cout << results.first << " " << results.second;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array of scores is small (for some unspecified value of "small") there's no need to sort the scores.

If I'm reading the question correctly, you're looking for the largest value that's less than `predict` and for the smallest value that's greater than `predict`. So do that:

```
int lower = INT_MAX;
int upper = INT_MIN;
for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
    if (scores[i] < predict)
        lower = std::max(lower, scores[i]);
    else
        upper = std::min(upper, scores[i]);
}
```

Note that if one of the scores is equal to `predict`, this code puts that value into `upper`. If that's not what you want you'll need to adjust the code accordingly.